# How can I calculate how much energy (in watt hours) my Mac laptop uses over a given time period?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to write some software that lets me calculate how much energy my Macbook M1 Air laptop uses over a period of time. My intention is to script this, and fire these numbers off periodically (once a day, maybe?) to a central location that allows me to track the total energy consumption of my device.

I've got a physical energy monitoring plug, but unfortunately, it doesn't have an API and because I move around a lot, there isn't an easy way for me to always use it when I plug my laptop in, hence why I'd like to see if there's a way to get similar information using software alone.

I've done a bit of research, and it looks like Mac's Activity Monitor tracks this on a per-application basis via the "Energy Score" metric, but I can't seem to extrapolate any watt hour usage out of this.

Is there a way I can get this information, somehow?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I measure power (energy consumption) with a Wattmeter. That is quite accurate. I don't think there is software to measure your PSU input (remember PSUs are not 100% efficient).

Comment: To be pedantic: energy usage over an amount of time is not expressed in Watt but in Watt-Hours (Wh).

Comment: Can't you use a Kill-A-Watt, or similar product? That way you're getting data even while the laptop is recharging while asleep, and you're accounting for inefficiencies in the power adapter.

Comment: @Spiff I've already got some hardware energy monitors (which are great!), but I'm trying to calculate the usage via software as this is part of an energy tracking project for calculating how much energy consumption work devices use across a large company -- with the intention of calculating a rough carbon footprint for work devices. It's impractical to use hardware monitors for all employees =/

Answer (score 6):

After many hours of tinkering, doing research, etc., I think I've stumbled across the best way to accomplish this using the `ioreg` CLI utility that is included with Apple's developer tools.

In the registry, Apple stores lots of hardware data, including information about your battery usage (so you can figure out the total amount of battery capacity in your laptop, as well as how many full cycles of charging it's been through), but it also includes information about your power adapter when plugged into a wall outlet, which is where things get interesting.

In my case, I don't actually care about how much the battery of the laptop is being used, because my end goal is to figure out how much energy a laptop consumes over a given time period, and the best way to do that would be to actually measure how much energy is being pulled in from a wall adapter -- this way, whenever a laptop is actively plugged in, I'd be logging this energy draw somewhere that I could eventually tally up to get an accurate representation over time.

It turns out that this data is available via the `ioreg` utility under the `AppleSmartBattery -> BatteryData -> AdapterPower` registry key. You can use the command below to grab the exact amount of watts being pulled from a wall adapter:

```
ioreg -rw0 -c AppleSmartBattery | grep BatteryData | grep -o '"AdapterPower"=[0-9]*' | cut -c 16- | xargs -I %  lldb --batch -o "    print/f %" | grep -o '$0 = [0-9.]*' | cut -c 6-
```

This command will query the data, convert it to the appropriate format (an IEEE754 float), and then output it to the console. In the end, you'll get a value that is either:

```
0
```

If you're not plugged into a wall adapter, meaning you aren't pulling any watts from an adapter. Or... a floating point number like this:

```
31.8184719
```

Which is the number of watts being drawn from the wall.

**P.S.** I used a hardware energy monitoring plug to confirm that the number of watts being drawn from the laptop is being reported the same between the hardware monitor and the `ioreg` utility as described above -- they were nearly identical, so I have a high degree of confidence that this method is accurate.

The next piece of the puzzle is to then convert the number of watts into a watt-hour measurement, which is the number of watts being pulled over the course of an hour.

I did some additional testing here, and what I learned is that the `ioreg` output information changes roughly once every 30 seconds or so, as it looks like the values it returns are cached.

To compute the number of watt-hours, what I ended up doing was the following:

1. Storing the number of watts consumed in a log file once every 60 seconds (via a simple cron script)
2. Dividing each of these watt measurements by 60 (since we're sampling once per minute)
3. Summing all of these measurements up (60 measurements = 1 hour) to compute the total number of watt-hours being used in as close to real-time as possible.

I ended up creating a [small GitHub repo](https://github.com/rdegges/energy-tracker) which contains the script and crontab file if you want to take a look.

**Problems With This Approach**

There are a few problems with the approach above that I don't know how to work around, but given that this is a software solution, I think it's as good as possible.

1. If the laptop is plugged into a wall charger but the laptop is off (or the software isn't running, like if the laptop is asleep), then obviously, no energy usage details will be logged.
2. You need to run a separate program to parse this energy log over time and sum things up in order to give you the total number of watt-hours that have been used by your laptop over a given time period. This isn't a big deal, but something to consider.

Comment: This is pretty cool. I think I'll add this to my zsh prompt.